# Inductive Proof, given $T(n) = \frac 25 T_{n-1} +\frac 35 T_{n-2},\; T_0 = 0, T_1=1$...

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have the following recurrence relation:

$T(n) = \dfrac{2}{5} \times T(n-1) + \dfrac{3}{5} \times T(n-2)$

with base cases:

$T(0) = 0$   &   $T(1) = 1$

I need help proving, by induction, that this relation is given by:

$T(n) = - \dfrac{(-3)^n - 5^n}{8 \times 5^{n-1}}$

PS: Apologies for the poor formatting. I'm brand new here.

Comment: What is `i`, should that be `n`?

Comment: Yes, i should have been n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE! For future reference, learn a bit of [MathJax syntax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can format your questions in a more legible form (it's basically $\LaTeX$).  Also, it's good to show that you've tried to work on the problem, and to point out where you got stuck, rather than to just ask for a solution.

---

When $n=0$, we have
$$T(0) = 0 = -\frac{(-3)^0-5^0}{8\cdot 5^{0-1}},$$
which agrees with the formula, starting the induction.

Now for the inductive step, suppose $T$ is given by your formula for all $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$. We need to show that $T(n+1)$ is also given by your formula. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
   T(n+1) &= \tfrac 25T(n)+\tfrac35T(n-1)\\[3pt]
          &= \frac25\Big(\frac{(-3)^n-5^n}{8\cdot5^{n-1}}\Big) + \frac35\Big(\frac{(-3)^{n-1}-5^{n-1}}{8\cdot5^{n-2}}\Big)\quad(\text{induction hypothesis})\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2(-3)^n-2(5^n)+5\cdot3(-3)^{n-1}-5\cdot3\cdot5^{n-1}}{8\cdot5^n}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2(-3)^n-2(5^n)-5\cdot(-3)(-3)^{n-1}-3\cdot5^n}{8\cdot5^n}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{-3(-3)^n-5(5^n)}{8\cdot5^n}=\frac{(-3)^{n+1}-5^{n+1}}{8\cdot5^{(n+1)-1}},
\end{align*}
which shows that your formula holds for the $n+1$ case.